# How to create a rule to match 2^3 to create a power operator?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

#### Given that I have the following grammar how would I add a rule to match something like `2^3` to create a `power` operator?

```
negation : '!'* term ;

unary : ('+'!|'-'^)* negation ;

mult : unary (('*' | '/' | ('%'|'mod') ) unary)* ;

add : mult (('+' | '-') mult)* ;

relation : add (('=' | '!=' | '<' | '<=' | '>=' | '>') add)* ;

expression : relation (('&&' | '||') relation)* ;

// LEXER ================================================================

HEX_NUMBER : '0x' HEX_DIGIT+;

fragment 
FLOAT: ;

INTEGER : DIGIT+ ({input.LA(1)=='.' && input.LA(2)>='0' && input.LA(2)<='9'}?=> '.' DIGIT+ {$type=FLOAT;})? ;

fragment
HEX_DIGIT : (DIGIT|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') ;

fragment
DIGIT : ('0'..'9') ;
```

#### What I have tried:

I tried something like `power : ('+' | '-') unary'^' unary` but that doesn't seem to work.

I also tried `mult : unary (('*' | '/' | ('%'|'mod') | '^' ) unary)* ;` but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give `^` higher precedence than `negation`, do this:

```
pow      : term ('^' term)* ;

negation : '!' negation | pow ;

unary    : ('+'! | '-'^)* negation ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consider the right-associativity already in the grammar, you can also use recursion:

```
   pow  :   term ('^'^ pow)?
        ;

   negation : '!'* pow;

   ...
```